# Redirect Only if Path is in Root (Rewrite Condition root)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect mypage.de/48153 to mypage.de/apo/48153 but if I add this rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /48153 /apo/#/48153
```

I think it will go into an infinite loop because the rule matches also the target.

I tried this:

```
# Rewrite sites to angular views (only if root)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(apo) [NC]
RedirectMatch 301 /48153 /apo/#/48153
```

to prevent from using the rule after the redirect. It changed the behavior there is no internal server error any more. But it breaks all of my AngularJs code.

And where is the difference to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^48153$ /apo/#/48153 [R=301,L]
```

If I alter the redirect e.g. `48152 -> 48153` all works, so I guess it does the redirects properly.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(48153)$ /apo/#/$1 [R=301,L,NE]` should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Rewrite ec sites to angular views (only if root)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(apo) [NC]
RewriteRule ^48153$ /apo/#/48153 [R=301,NE,L]
```

This did the trick for me. The `NE` prevents the `#` from being escaped. I guess the `RewriteCond` is not needed because the Rewriterule uses the `L` tag.